# Non-intrusive extension of Rcpp with Rcpp::traits::Exporter

Tags: r, rcpp, r-package, s-expression

I am writing an Rcpp package with classes containing base Rcpp objects that are non-intrusively exported to C++ types (see [Extending Rcpp](https://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/Rcpp-extending.pdf) by Eddelbuettel and Francois, and this [helpful vignette](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/) by coatless).

What this means is that if I have a class `foo::bar` and a constructor for `foo::bar` given a `SEXP`, I can call a function like this:

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
void func(foo::bar object){
   // do something
}
```

My problem is that `sourceCpp("foobar.cpp")` works exactly as expected, but `R CMD build` complains about the `RcppExports.cpp` file missing declarations for this new class.

Here is a minimum reproducible example, containing a `foo::bar` class holding a single `Rcpp::NumericVector`. It compiles with `sourceCpp()` but the package will not build because `foobar` is not found in `RcppExports.cpp`:

**foobar.cpp:**

```
#include <RcppCommon.h>

// forward declare class
namespace foo {
    class bar;
}

// forward declare Rcpp::as<> Exporter
template <>
class Rcpp::traits::Exporter<foo::bar>;

#include <Rcpp.h>

// now fully declare class, since Rcpp objects 
//   are now loaded from Rcpp.h
namespace foo {
    class bar {
        public:
        Rcpp::NumericVector x;
        bar(Rcpp::NumericVector x) : x(x) {};
    };
}

// now fully declare Rcpp exporter, since we can
//   deal with Rcpp objects from Rcpp.h
namespace Rcpp {
    namespace traits {
        template <>
        class Exporter<foo::bar> {
            Rcpp::NumericVector x_;

            public:
            Exporter(SEXP x) : x_(x) {}

            foo::bar get() {
                return foo::bar(x_);
            }
        };
    }
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector test(foo::bar& A) {
    return A.x;
}
```

The specific errors I am getting when running `R CMD check` are all in the `src/RcppExports.cpp` file:

- 'foo' has not been declared
- 'A' was not declared in this scope
- 'foo' was not declared in this scope
- 'template argument 1 is invalid
- 'qualified-id in declaration before 'A'

What needs to happen to get the package to build just like `sourceCpp`?

Thanks for any solutions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> RcppExports.cpp file missing declarations for this new class.

See the Attributes vignette. The custom behavior is to have a header named as the package (i.e. `foo.h` for package `foo`) and/or `foo-types.h`) which will be added to the generated `RcppExports.cpp`.

That is documented but hidden rather too effectively :-/   It's here too so we could close this as a dupe but I don't have time to search that now.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel!  Well documented indeed but hidden effectively.  This is awesome, and it really helps out with the RcppSparse package I'm working on, and a functional Rcpp sparse matrix class header should now be on CRAN in short order.

Comment: Awesome!  And congrats on getting RcppClock -- haven't had a chance to look at it though.

Comment: always happy to write a vignette for RcppGallery on RcppClock.  It's actually quite fun to benchmark pieces of Rcpp code with C++ timers and get the results delivered right into the R session at runtime :)

Comment: I once "started" (in the sense of an initial test package) two benchmark packages based on C++ infrastructure. But it seems hard / impossible / real work to get the data 'back up into R' so I never progressed.  The initial exploratioins still on github in rcppgeiger and rcppbenchmark ...   So yes, if you have an interesting point to make or illustrate the Gallery is always listening :)

Comment: Just submitted a PR on RcppGallery.  To get the data "back up into R" I just use Rcpp to create a data.frame (well, S3 class) as a global variable in the R environment.  It's pretty simple really -- wrap std::chrono::high_resolution clock on the C++ side, write a few S3 methods on the R side.  Seems like you went a bit deeper with rcppgeiger on the benchmarking side, I'm sure one can do better than just wrapping calls to C++ chrono.